# MODx Evolution Weblogin: Redirect to requested page once logged in

Tags: code-snippets, modx, modx-evolution

I am sending out a newsletter and I will have links that go to secured pages. How do I set up WebLogin to redirect to the originally requested page once the user has logged in?

This is the behavior that I want:

1. Enter the URL www.mysite.com/protectedpage
2. Redirected to login page.
3. Successful login.
4. Redirected back to www.mysite.com/protectedpage

Using

- MODx Evolution 1.0.14
- WebLogin 1.1
- PHP Version 5.3.6
- Apache 2.0
- MySQL 5.1.46

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Being an Evolution extra the documentation is extremely light, however the source code suggests that WebLogin will take note of `$_REQUEST["refurl"]` ([see git](https://github.com/jgrau/MODx-CMS/blob/master/assets/snippets/weblogin/weblogin.processor.inc.php#L401)) which looks like it supports both resource alias and resource id.

Try adding a hidden form element to your login page with the id of your protected resource.

```
<input type="hidden" name="refurl" value="PROTECTED_PAGE_ID" />
```